# How to add a multiple image selector in a prestashop backoffice module?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i'm using prestashop and i'm trying to develope a backoffice modulethat make me upload multiple images (from backoffice, like selecting product images).

until now i found just how to add a single file selector in the fields_form

```
'FR_START' => [
                'type' => 'file',
                'label' => $this->l('FR START'),
                'name' => 'FR_START',
                'display_image' => true,
                'image' => $image_fr_start_url ? $image_fr_start_url : false
            ],
```

actualy i'm looking for a way that allow me to choose multiple images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. You could use `HelperImageUploader` class. An example of how to use is on Prestashop `AdminProductsController` class inside `initFormImages` function.
2. There is a param `multiple` for `HelperUploader` class used by `file` type in forms. Check all params at `generate` function in `\classes\helper\HelperForm.php` class.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: Please, mark answer as valid if helps you ;) Good luck